# Duplicating the rows and columns of image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to take an image and output a larger image whose height and width are twice as much as those of the input image, by duplicating the rows and columns.

I have implemented this with the code below; however, the output is an entirely black image.

```
img = imread('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/png/lena.png');

[M1,N1] = size(img);

M2 = M1*2;
N2 = N1*2;
g = zeros(M2,N2);
imshow(g);
```

The program should generate a larger image where the height and width are twice as much as those of the input image.

Comment: The image you are showing with `imshow(g)` is only the result of the `zeros` function, so I assume it will be only 0, so a black image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While @sardar-usama 's answer is likely what you want to do in practice, strictly speaking it doesn't duplicate the rows/columns as the question requested.  Rather, it interpolates the image to the new size (though, imresize includes options on how to perform the interpolation).

If you actually wanted to duplicate the rows and columns, you can do:
`g = repelem(img,2,2);`

Comment: Or `n = 2; g = img(ceil(1/n:1/n:end), ceil(1/n:1/n:end));`

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion I have if you somehow don't have access to `repelem` is to create a [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of coordinates that introduces 0.5 coordinates in each dimension, remove the decimals with `floor` then index into the image.  You'll have to convert the coordinates into linear indices via [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) before indexing.

In other words:

```
img = imread('https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/png/lena.png');
[M1,N1] = size(img);

% Create grid of coordinates at twice the frequency
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:N1+0.5, 1:0.5:M1+0.5);

% Remove decimal precision
X = floor(X);
Y = floor(Y);

% Convert to linear indices and sample
ind = sub2ind([M1, N1], Y, X);
g = img(ind);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I don't find an efficient [`repelem`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583212/6579744) I may use [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
g = kron(img , ones(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

To resize the image and duplicate the pixels, use [`imresize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imresize.html) with the nearest neighbour interpolation method.

```
g = imresize(img,2,'nearest');  %resizing to twice the size of the original image
```

Now you can see:

```
>> size(img)  
ans =  
   512   512

>> size(g)  
ans =  
   1024  1024
```

---

You didn't duplicate any row/column in your code. Rather you initialised a zero matrix of twice the size of `img`. A matrix of all zeros is nothing but a black image which is what you're getting.

Comment: One thing that is paramount is if you want to duplicate the information, you must use **nearest neighbour** interpolation: `g = imresize(img, 2, 'nearest');`.  Otherwise, you will be using bicubic interpolation by default and the output image pixels will not be the same as if you duplicated the rows and columns.